# Simple UIButton Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, uibutton, action

I have 1 button and 2 methods. One method calls this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(action1) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

And the other calls this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(action2) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

For some reason, the button's action will not change. I am sure I am calling the above code correctly. Is it trying to add an action to the button and making it call both functions? If so, how can I stop this from happening? I have tried releasing and setting the button to nil before setting the new action and no luck. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's actually calling `action1` and `action2`. You need to call [`removeTarget`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/removeTarget%3aaction%3aforControlEvents%3a) before adding the new target on the button.

Comment: Does this look good or do I need to add the action to remove? Will this remove all the actions attached to it?  [button removeTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];

Comment: @Preston: yes, by using `nil` you are telling **CocoaTouch** to remove all actions from target.